# Pointing my domain from godaddy to ec2 Ubuntu wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Please how do I point my domain directly to the paajoe directory ? When I enter paajoe.com I see this two directory but I want to go directly to the paajoe directory.

Comment: You need to configure your web server to serve the directory you want.  See the documentation.

Comment: Please how do I that ?

Comment: That completely depends on which web server you use.  Read the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

This would require an update to your web server configuration which would differ depending on which web server you are using. Typically, it'll be Apache or NGINX.

If Apache, you need to update the DocumentRoot and Directory values within your configuration file while would typically live in /etc/apache2/sites-available/.

If NGINX, you need to update the root value within your configuration file which would typically live in /etc/nginx/sites-available/.

Here are a couple of links which would help in either situation:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-move-an-nginx-web-root-to-a-new-location-on-ubuntu-16-04

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-move-an-apache-web-root-to-a-new-location-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: Okay.  It was helpful but I got more help from this link instead https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts

Comment: Great. I can't recommend the Digital Ocean tutorials enough, always try there when you're stuck with things like this.